# Cannot read value from the GET response

Tags: javascript

*TL:DR below*

So, I'm on one of Spring tutorials right now making an REST API app. In the back-end there is an email verification service which gets token to verify and after verification it gives simple response with status "SUCCESS" or "ERROR" - all that stuff works just fine. At the front there is simple HTML page with one JS script which suppose to check this response status and according to its value should display different message in HTML body. The problem is JS cannot read the value from response (I pressume) because no matter what it always gives me "else" option. I have no JS knowledge, I tried my best to figure it out on my own but didn't make it.

**TL:DR
JS script cannot read "operationStatus" value from the response.**

JS script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
            if (urlParams.has('token')){
                verifyToken(urlParams.get('token'));
            }

            function verifyToken(tokenValue) {
                $.get('http://localhost:8080/mobile-app-ws/users/email-verification', {token: tokenValue})
                    .done(function (response) {

                        if (response["operationStatus"] === "SUCCESS"){
                            $("#not-successful-result").attr("style", "display: none !important;");
                            $("#unknown-result").attr("style", "display: none !important;");
                            $("#successful-result").attr("style", "display: block !important;");
                        }else if (response["operationStatus"] === "ERROR"){
                            $("#successful-result").attr("style", "display: none !important;");
                            $("#unknown-result").attr("style", "display: none !important;");
                            $("#not-successful-result").attr("style", "display: block !important;");
                        }else{
                            console.log(response);
                            $("#successful-result").attr("style", "display: none !important;");
                            $("#not-successful-result").attr("style", "display: none !important;");
                            $("#unknown-result").attr("style", "display: block !important;");
                        }

                })
            }
        })
    </script>
```

HTML body:

```
<body>
    <div id="successful-result" style="display:none">Successful verification</div>
    <div id="not-successful-result" style="display:none">Verification link has expired</div>
    <div id="unknown-result" style="display:none">UNKNOWN</div>
</body>
```

JAVA response class (RequestOperationStatus and RequestOperationName are just simple enums)

```
public class OperationStatusModel {

    private RequestOperationStatus operationStatus;
    private RequestOperationName operationName;

}
```

Example response from Postman in JSON:

```
{
    "operationStatus": "ERROR",
    "operationName": "VERIFY_EMAIL"
}
```

And console in browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuK6g.png

Comment: Based on the console output, you're getting back an XML document of some sort. You may need to add an `Accept: application/json` header or similar to tell the server to send you JSON.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with output. Script couldn't read value from XML. Changing Java method to produce JSON resolves the problem. Also change in JS to "getJSON" instead of "get" works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) else you have to pass `Accept: application/json`.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/mobile-app-ws/users/email-verification', {token: tokenValue})
    .done(function (response) {
        // ...
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if (response["operationStatus"] === "SUCCESS")
...
}else if (response["operationStatus"] === "ERROR"){
```

to

```
if (response.OperationStatusModel.operationStatus === "SUCCESS")
...
}else if (response.OperationStatusModel.operationStatus === "ERROR"){
```

If that does not work. Look what is in response. Try this. Before the line

```
 if (response["operationStatus"] === "SUCCESS"){
```

put a console.log, like this

```
console.log(response);
```